# A structural transformation package?

Tags: software-recommendations, proteins, structure

What are some of the structural (protein) transformation packages available, which can change a bond length, angle or dihedral?

Comment: In principle, with a text editor you can modify the structure file manually. Also, must of the visualization/editor molecular programs can do what you want.

Comment: As Camps notes, this might be a little too broad. In theory, almost any molecule visualization software can do this, plus a number of other packages like ASE, or even direct text editors. Could you narrow the scope of what you are looking for?

Comment: Something like the VMD structure transformation capabilities (translate, rotate...) but without the graphical interface.

Comment: @Camps are you able to write an answer now, based on the response by BND?

Comment: I still feel this is very broad, even excluding GUI programs (many of which also have a commandline interface that would satisfy your question). I think you should edit the question to narrow it down, rather than adding details in the comments.

Comment: Without additional detail explaining the difference, I think the duplicate addresses your question. While many of these programs are graphical, most listed there also have a console or script interface to change geometric parameters.